# Subscribe to IONIC2 provider is not sync with pages and custom components

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-promise, subscribe

Here's my subscribe-able Cart Provider where `.cart` is subscribe-able

```
@Injectable()
export class CartProvider {

  cart: Observable<Array<CartItem>>
  private _cart: BehaviorSubject<Array<CartItem>>;
  private cartStore: Array<CartItem> = [];

  constructor(private dialogs: DialogsProvider) {
    this._cart = <BehaviorSubject<Array<CartItem>>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this.cart = this._cart.asObservable();
  }

  /**
   * return obs array cart
   * 
   * @returns {Observable<Array<CartItem>>} 
   * @memberof CartProvider
   */
  getCart(): Observable<Array<CartItem>> {
    return this.cart;
  }
```

when I attempt to subsscribe to changes on Ionic pages it work fine

```
  export class ItemsPage 
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  items: Array<CartItem>;
  cartDisplay:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams , private cart:CartProvider
  ) {
    cart.getCart().subscribe((val) => {
      this.cartDisplay = val.length;
    });
  }
```

but when I attempted to use the same method `cart.getCart()` It fails to watch changes on `CartProvider.cart` so it fails to change the value on the custom component html when the same exact codes work at Ionic Page

```
    <button ion-button clear icon-only (click)="showCart()">
        <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
        <span class="badge" *ngIf="cartDisplay > 0">{{cartDisplay}}</span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE::**

I solved this issue by adding CartProvider to CustomComponent providers Array Like that

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartComponent } from './cart';
import { CartProvider } from "../../providers/cart/cart";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ 
    CartComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(CartComponent),
  ],
  exports: [
    CartComponent
  ],
  providers:[
    CartProvider // <-------- added here instead of adding it to component.providers array
  ]
})
export class CartComponentModule {}
```